# Get the last stored localStorage item

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Say we have:

```
localStorage.setItem("key1", "value1");
localStorage.setItem("key2", "value2");
localStorage.setItem("key3", "value3");
localStorage.setItem("key4", "value4");
localStorage.setItem("key5", "value5"); // the last one
```

Is there a way to get the last stored item, without a knowledge of its key? So, we don't know if its key is `key5` or `key10` or `fbjfbjfkbjkf`. We just want to get this item.

Something like?

```
localStorage.getLastStoredItem();
```

Comment: Does [StorageEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageEvent) do what you want?

Comment: No, if you want a timeline of your write operations you'll have to create it yourself. What is your actual use case?

Comment: I think this is impossible, without remembering the last key yourself. The order of `localStorage.keys` is not guaranteed; Chrome seems to return the keys in alphabetical order.

Comment: proof for torazaburos point: https://jsfiddle.net/taqcsz5m/

Comment: IE returns the values in the order they have been set in. In Firefox the order of the returned keys does not appear to make any sense at all.

Comment: @torazaburo Your words about  alphabetical order brings the light to another my problem, thanks for it! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`localStorage` has no exact concept (it is implementation-defined) of the order of items stored, it should be used as a key-value store.

The simplest solution for you would be to somehow store the last key entered. For example, you can create a wrapper function that stores your items, and updates the last key:

```
var lastKey; // somewhere in your code, in the outer scope of `add()` and `getLast()`

// ...

function add(key, value) {
    lastKey = key;                    
    localStorage.setItem(key, value);
}

function getLast() {
    return localStorage.getItem(lastKey);
}
```

[Here's a sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/92msrmcb/1/)

Maybe you can make an object for your storage purposes that will keep track of all of this. You can also encapsulate the `lastKey` as a private variable through a closure so you can't accidentally change it:

```
var MyStorage = {};
(function(s) {
    var lastKey;
    s.add = function(key, value) { /* ... */ };
    s.getLast = function() { /* ... */ }
})(MyStorage);
```

Now only `MyStorage.add()` and `MyStorage.getLast()` can access the `lastKey`. Also, if you use a wrapper object like `MyStorage`, you can for example change your store to `sessionStorage` internally without affecting any code using `MyStorage`

---

**EDIT**

As suggested in the comments by **user2181397** and **nnnnnn**, if you want to persist the value of `lastKey` through application restarting, you can also store it in `localStorage` (or `sessionStorage` depending on your app logic):

```
var lastKey = localStorage.getItem('lastKey');
```

Or in the object:

```
var MyStorage = {};
(function(s) {
    var lastKey = localStorage.getItem('lastKey');
    s.add = function(key, value) { /* ... */ };
    s.getLast = function() { /* ... */ }
})(MyStorage);
```

---

**EDIT2:**

> Something like? `localStorage.getLastStoredItem;`

Another way could be to add the above method directly to `localStorage` by overriding the `Storage.prototype` methods instead of creating the `MyStorage` object:

```
(function(s) {
    var lastKey = localStorage.getItem('lastKey');

    var _setItem = Storage.prototype.setItem;          // remember the original setItem
    Storage.prototype.setItem = function(key, value) { // define the new setItem
        if (this === window.localStorage) {            // make sure we are calling localStorage's methods
            lastKey = key;                             // remember the last key
        } 
        _setItem.apply(this, arguments);               // call the original setItem
    }

    Storage.prototype.getLast = function() {           // create the necessary custom method to get the last item stored
        if (this === window.localStorage) {            // make sure we are calling localStorage's methods
            return this.getItem.call(this, lastKey);
        }
    }
})();
```

Usage:

```
localStorage.setItem('key1', 'val1');
console.log(localStorage.getLast()); // logs 'val1'
```

[Here's a sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ovs3g3yr/3/)

*NOTE*: Since we are editing `Storage.prototype`, extending this functionality to other `Storage` API methods is just a matter of removing the `if (this === localStorage)` or adding another condition to it.

Comment: How & where you can store the last key? Suppose  an user restart the application so lastKey variable  will be initialized again and previous value will be gone. So in that case browser wont know what is mean by lastKey

Comment: Store the last key itself in local storage, so that it persists between sessions...

Comment: Didn't consider this use case since OP didn't mention the exact purpose he needs this for, good suggestions though, I added them to my answer.

Comment: That works, and also a fanstastic amount of information for my self-education. Thanks!

Comment: @john1121 glad to help :)

Comment: @nem , can you help me one another time? I tried to use the first example, but if I use `removeItem(lastKey)`, it doesn't work. I posted my fork of your code here: https://jsfiddle.net/92msrmcb/5/ . /// Actually I'm trying to create a script for Chrome's bookmark manager, so it would act more intuitive and ease. If you also interested in it, I can upload it to github. It almost done.

Comment: The issue is that you are removing the last stored item, but **not updating** the `lastKey` so when you call `getLastStored()`, `lastKey` is still the old value but you deleted that item and so `null` is appropriately returned... If you want the removal to properly update the last key as well, you need to maintain a list of keys instead of a single variable and use the last entry as the last key... here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/horohbsr/1/

Comment: Great, this works! Thanks again! Also I made a small fix for myself - I changed `var keys = [];` to `function myFunc() { keys = []; } myFunc();`.